# HTTP headers are missing in IIS server variable "ALL_HTTP" in integrated mode

Tags: c#, iis, siteminder

Siteminder HTTP headers are missing in IIS server variable "ALL_HTTP" in integrated mode. We are using Request.ServerVariable("ALL_HTTP") to get SM_USER. HTTP_SM_USER is missing in ALL_HTTP. The same code is working on different server.

Answer (score 2):

The server variables collection (ALL_HTTP) is an old mechanism from back in the ASP days. You should look at the context headers, which is the preferred method now in .Net. You can see your headers via *Context.Request.Headers* instead of Request.ServerVariables, like in this code snippet:

```
<%
    headers.DataSource = Context.Request.Headers.ToDictionary();
    headers.DataBind();
%>
<ul>
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="headers">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <li>
            <%# Eval("Key") %> = <%# Eval("Value") %>
         </li>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```